# Getting runtime error in simple SPOJ task JAVA

Tags: java, runtime

First of all I would like to say that I am a total novice when it comes to programming so the problem may appear to be trivial but I just can't figure it out. 
Whenever I try to submit an answer to this problem http://www.spoj.com/problems/GNY07A/  I keep on getting runtime error even though the output seems to be correct

Here is the code:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

 public class PrimeGenerator{

 public static void main(String[] args){

      Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
      String wordLength = new String();
      String output = new String();
      int linenumber = 1;


 int i = userInput.nextInt();


 while(i>=1||i<=1000){

 int wordlength;

     String dataset = userInput.next();
     String dataset2 = userInput.next();


     boolean haslowercase = !dataset2.equals(dataset2.toLowerCase());

     if(!haslowercase){
         break;
     }else{

     wordLength = String.valueOf(dataset);

     int dataset2length = dataset2.length();

    wordlength = Integer.parseInt(wordLength);
     if(wordlength>80){
         break;
     }
     else{

         if(wordlength>dataset2length){
             break;
         }else{

     output = dataset2.substring(0,wordlength-1)+ dataset2.substring(wordlength,dataset2.length());

     System.out.println(linenumber+" "+output);
     linenumber++;
         }
     }
     }
 }








}
```

}

Comment: I'm pretty sure this: `wordLength = String.valueOf(dataset);` would produce a compiler error

Comment: Changed to  wordLength = dataset; instead but the same error showed up

Comment: Should be `wordLength = Integer.parseInt(dataset);` if I understood the code correctly (if not, please correct me). Reading up on SPOJ, class should be declared as `public class Main` for all files you submit

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int times = input.nextInt();
        for(int i = 1; i <= times; ++i){
            int index = input.nextInt()-1;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.next());
            System.out.println(i + " " + sb.deleteCharAt(index).toString());
        }
    }
}
```